# create search result using PDO prepare statement gives error

Tags: php, search

when i am using

```
if(!in_array($search_each, $commonwords))
```

this code gives error without this it works fine
i want to create search result but excluding some **common words** ,if not using **common words** this code works fine...

below is the search result fetch from database

```
$t=strtolower($_POST['e']);
$commonwords = 'a,an,and,I,it,is,do,does,for,from,go,how,the,flat,offers,offer,etc';

$commonwords = explode(",", $commonwords);

if( strlen( $t ) <= 10 )
    echo "";
else {

    $search_exploded = explode ( " ", $t );
    $construct = '';
    foreach( $search_exploded as $search_each ) {
        if(!in_array($search_each, $commonwords)){
            $construct .="AND d_title LIKE ? ";
         }
    }

    include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/deal/database/db.php";
    $query =$con1->prepare("SELECT * 
                            FROM deals 
                            WHERE 1 $construct 
                            ORDER BY `d_id` DESC ");

    $params = array_map(function($term) { return "%$term%"; }, 
    $search_exploded);
    $query->execute($params);
    $found=$query->rowCount();
    if($found == 0){
        echo "no Result Found"; 
    }else{ 
        while($row_de=$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            $de_id=$row_de['d_id'];
            $de_title=$row_de['d_title'];
            $d_logo=$row_de['d_logo']   ;       
            $d_type=$row_de['d_type'];  
            echo  $de_title;
        }
```

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Print query before use in prepared statement and show in question.

Answer (score 0):

if(!in_array($search_each, $commonwords))
this above line works fine,

think so there will issue in $search_exploded, check this variable it has value or not
$search_exploded = explode ( " ", $t );